# Evaluating $\sum_{i = 0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} {n \choose 2i}p^{2i}(1 - p)^{n - 2i}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, binomial-distribution

Let $0 \leq p \leq 1$, $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$ and consider $$\sum_{i = 0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} {n \choose 2i}p^{2i}(1 - p)^{n - 2i}$$ Has anyone a hint for me how I can calculate the sum?

Comment: You are looking for the probability a random variable with Binomial distribution $\mathrm{Bin}(n,p)$ is even. The answer is $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}(1-2p)^n$: see e.g. [this post on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16187/binomial-distribution-parity/). (Three methods are given there.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_k\binom{n}{2k}p^{2k}(1-p)^{n-2k}
&=\frac12\left[\sum_k\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}+\sum_k(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\right]\\[6pt]
&=\frac12\left[1+(1-2p)^n\right]
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

If $n$ is even and $q = 1-p$

$$(p+q)^n = \sum_{i=0}^{n/2}\binom{n}{2i}p^{2i}q^{n-2i} + \sum_{i=0}^{n/2-1}\binom{n}{2i+1}p^{2i+1}q^{n-2i-1}$$

$$(-p+q)^n = \sum_{i=0}^{n/2}\binom{n}{2i}(-p)^{2i}q^{n-2i} + \sum_{i=0}^{n/2-1}\binom{n}{2i+1}(-p)^{2i+1}q^{n-2i-1}$$

$$\implies (-p+q)^n = \sum_{i=0}^{n/2}\binom{n}{2i}p^{2i}q^{n-2i} - \sum_{i=0}^{n/2-1}\binom{n}{2i+1}p^{2i+1}q^{n-2i-1}$$

So, the required quantity is $((p+q)^n + (-p+q)^n)/2 = \frac{1+(1-2p)^n}{2}$

When $n$ is odd,

> $$(p+q)^n = \sum_{i=0}^{(n-1)/2}\binom{n}{2i}p^{2i}q^{n-2i} + \sum_{i=0}^{(n-1)/2}\binom{n}{2i+1}p^{2i+1}q^{n-2i-1}$$

And a similar calculation as above will get you,

> the same answer as before.

Answer (score 1):

Sum of Even terms in the binomial expression Bin(n,p) $=\frac{1}{2}*[(p+1-p)^{n}+(p-(1-p))^{n}]$

=$\frac{1}{2}*[1+(1-2p)^{n}]$

Comment: Check this answer when $n=1$.

Comment: got it Changed where it need to be

Comment: when $n=1$, this gives $p$, but the sum gives $1-p$.

Comment: Just the usage of what is p and (1-p) I have kept the answer the same but changed the Bin(n,1-p)

Comment: Since the $p$ in your answer does not match the $p$ in the question, it might confuse the unwary.

Comment: I will change it, you are right.